# Chrome extension with vite not working though the vite preview is working

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, vite

I have a vite page developed. It works fine with vite preview but doesn't load in the chrome extension. It shows blank. Even with a live server also it shows blank.
here is my Vite config

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import postcss from './postcss.config.js'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    base: './',
    define: {
        'process.env': process.env
    },
    css: {
        postcss,
    },
    plugins: [react()],
    resolve: {
        alias: [{
            find: /^~.+/,
            replacement: (val) => {
                return val.replace(/^~/, "");
            },
        }, ],
    },
    build: {
        commonjsOptions: {
            transformMixedEsModules: true,
        }
    }
})
```

I Tried launching the live server from the `dist` folder or loading the HTML. In the Chrome dev console, it shows the js and the CSS getting loaded but the div with root is not getting replaced. Also, there is no error on the Chrome console.

Few more updates after debugging ...
The live server also works without the `index.html` and similarly, the preview server fails if I add the `index.html` in the URL. But this still doesn't solve my problem to load it into a Chrome extension.

Comment: I have found the issue and the solution. It was the problem with the routing in my code. Because the router was taking /index.html as a route it was not finding any compoment for that and showing blank screen.